# Interrupted transactions and lazy loading

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kotlin, transactions

Currently, I have this code:

```
@Transactional
fun apiMethod() {
  val entity: SomeEntity = myRepo.find()
  methodWithDbCalls1(entity)
  methodWithExternalCalls(entity)
  methodWithDbCalls2(entity)
}
```

Because I have `@Transactional` on the top-level method all DB manipulation (including `entity`) runs in a single transaction.

Now, `methodWithExternalCalls` calls some 3rd party service and these requests take a long time so it's not a good idea to block the whole transaction by that. So instead I want to wrap only the methods `methodWithDbCalls1` and `methodWithDbCalls2` into `@Transactional`, while `methodWithExternalCalls` must not run in a transaction at all. **The trouble now is that the `entity` is of course lazily loaded, so by dropping the encompassing transaction, I start getting lazy initialization exceptions.**

My question is how to handle that. Two solutions come to my mind, neither of them ideal:

- prefetch those `entity` properties which are needed by either of the inner methods. This has the disadvantage that the outer method would be tightly bound to the inner methods logic. Moreover, it seems a little bit hacky.
- materialize the `entity` into a suitable DTO. This seems a little bit cleaner but actually suffers from the same issue because "suitable DTO" again means tailor-made to the inner methods' usage.

Are there any better solutions? **I'm especially interested in those that can avoid the necessity of the outer method knowing about the inner workings of the inner ones**.

Comment: Not sure if that will resolve the problem or not, but as you mention that the current code has it all in 1 single transaction, perhaps instead of removing the top level transactional entirely you could put an Transactional with propagation_requires_new on the two db calls, forcing them to be called in their own transaction, while the outer transaction is temporarily suspended.

Comment: The main motivation for doing this redesign is to avoid connection pool exhaustion, so running the expensive calls inside another transaction is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with your current solutions for the LazyInitializationException.
The only other solution I can offer (but not recommend) is applying eager fetching to the relevant instance variables of the Entity class. I'd go with a DTO myself.

However, considering that methodWithDbCalls1, methodWithExternalCalls and methodWithDbCalls2 would be run in sequence based on your example, your transaction would still be blocked until the external calls were completed because the transaction would still be in use in the outer method call. Removing the transaction context from the inner method would do nothing to fix that.

You may want to consider using non-blocking calls for your external logic, perhaps with an Executor. That way the transaction and all logic that has to be executed within it can continue. If the following database calls require information from your long external requests, there's nothing to be done but wait for the information.

Comment: To clarify:

> your transaction would still be blocked until
I forgot to mention that I want to remove the outer transaction. I thought that was implied by the requirement "methodWithExternalCalls must not run in a transaction", though.

> the following database calls require information from your long external requests
That's unfortunately exactly my situation.